# How can I "un-activate" the active layer in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers

I like to use GIMP with the <kbd>show layer boundary</kbd> setting **on**  so that when I'm working with a layer a dashed border appears around it.

[image]

However, once I am finished working with the layer - and I'd simply like to view and consider the state of the image - I'd like to dismiss the border by deselecting/deactivating the layer as I find the dashed border distracting.
So far the best solution I have come up with  is to select another layer - that is less prominent, but this is not ideal, I'd like it to go away completely.
To be clear, I want to  keep <kbd>show layer boundary</kbd> **on** so that in general active layers are bordered, I just want the border to go away by having no layers selected/active.
How can I do this in GIMP 2.8?

Comment: Have you tried Select > None (ctrl-shift-a)?

Comment: That's a layer boundary, not a selection frame.

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't find any native ability to unselect layers in GIMP, this is the (hacky) workaround, I have come up with, I thought I would post this as an answer in case it might be of use to others.
I created a new layer called `focus_holder`, 1px in size (minimum GIMP would allow) and positioned it under the background.

[image: create][image: layers]

Then when I want to remove focus away from my "real" layers so that I don't see the borders (also so that if I do something unintentional, like accidentally hit a key on my keyboard I won't rename a "real" layer) I select `focus_holder`.

Comment: This is clever, but gimp should have a built-in solution, for exactly the reasons you express

Answer (score 2):

You could select a channel instead of a layer (that is usually a major problem actually). One functionality that creates a new channel, and move the focus to it is `Select->Save to channel` - it works regardless of an active selection existing or not.

You can assign a shortcut to it (enable Dynamic keyboard shortcuts in `preferences->interface`, then hover over the `Save to channel` option on the `select` menu and press a key for it (I like to use numbers 1-9 as shortcuts)) - then you can at any time hit "1", followed by `ctrl + l` (to make the Layers dialog visible again if you want) - and the focused drawable will be the channel, which is always the same size as the image.

Comment: Good information, it's especially useful to know about this for times when focus could be "secretly" held by the channel - and you can't figure out why GIMP is not behaving as expected!